# Why onChange() called twice when fragment recreated

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I'm trying to use the new android architectural components, but I am confused one moment.

I created a ViewModel class

```
public class BuyViewModel extends ViewModel {

private BuyRepository buyRepository;
private LiveData<Adverts> advertsLiveData;
private boolean isLoading;
private int currentPage;

@Inject
public BuyViewModel(BuyRepository buyRepository) {
    this.buyRepository = buyRepository;
}

public void init(int currentPage) {
    this.currentPage = currentPage;
    if (this.advertsLiveData != null) {
        return;
    }
    Timber.tag("logi").d("BuyViewModel > init -> ");
    advertsLiveData = buyRepository.getAdverts(currentPage);
}

public LiveData<Adverts> getAdvertsLiveData() {
    return advertsLiveData;
}
}
```

Observe LiveData in my LifeCycleFragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    buyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(BuyViewModel.class);
    buyViewModel.init(1);
    buyViewModel.getAdvertsLiveData().observe(this, adverts -> {
        Timber.tag("logi").d("BuyFragment > onActivityCreated -> ");
        assert adverts != null;
        adapter.addMoreAdverts(adverts.getResults());
    });

    setupViews();
}
```

But when I replaced this Fragment with another and switched back to this Fragment, the method `onChange` was called twice and  added two portions of the same data in `rvAdapter`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I SOLVED THIS!!!
When I creating my ViewModel class, I pass "this" 1-st parameter into method

`buyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(**this**, viewModelFactory).get(BuyViewModel.class);`

But I need pass "getActivity()", and code looks like that

`buyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(**getActivity()**,viewModelFactory).get(BuyViewModel.class);`

Comment: This didn't work for me onChange() is still triggered

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing "this" inside fragment - it takes the instance of your fragment. After your configuration changing, onDestroy() of your fragment does not call (where unsubsription should be done), but only onDestroyView(). So, when you passed instance of your activity, it unsubsribed, because onDestroy() of your activity was called.